# Validation rule checking for a combination of text and picklist fields

Tags: validation

I have to write a validation on opp with the following criteria:

When the combinations is as follows:

```
Opp stage='Closed-Won'
and (payment1__c!=Null && payment2!==null)
```

Here the `payment1__c` is a text field whereas the `payemnt2__c` is a picklist field.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the validation ?

Answer (score 3):

I think your validation rule should look something like what follows:

```
AND(Stage != "Closed-Won", IsEmpty(payment1__c), IsEmpty(isPickval(payment2__c))
```

You want to test text fields for IsEmpty(), not against Null. You also want a validation rule to return false for the condition you want to be true.